# Postsharp 4 issue

Tags: postsharp

I had just installed **postsharp 4** on some of my csproj's, on all of them except for one everything works great but on one I have an irritating problem.

I will explain:
I have 2 csproj's: **A.csproj** and **AService.csproj**, **AService.csproj** has a reference to **A.csproj** which means all of it's references should be added to **AService.csproj**.

Among those references I got the reference to **postsharp 4**.
When I build my solution on Debug everything works great, I see the **postsharp.dll** in the **AService\bin\Debug** directory among all the other assemblies, but when I build on Release it doesn't add it.

I tried adding it manually, tried from nuget several times but nothing seems to happen, the dll just won't be added to **AService\bin\Release**.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue by adding under **<'OutputPath'>bin\Release\<'/OutputPath'>** there is     **<'DefineConstants'>TRACE<'/DefineConstants'>**  after the **TRACE** you need to add **;DBNAME** and it works!

Comment: That doesn't seem like it had any relation to PostSharp, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, at the end is was an internal issue in our application.